# Multi-threaded random number generator keeps getting a SegFault at initstate_r function

Tags: c, multithreading, random

I'm trying to develop a program in C that will generate a given number of random integers. It is supposed to use a given number of threads to speed this up. I found out that the regular random function won't work with threads and am now using random_r instead. I keep getting a SegFault at the initstate_r function, which doesn't make sense because I'm trying to initialize variables, not access them. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? (The initstate_r function needs to stay in the generateRandomNumbers function.)

Here is the code:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>  // must include stdio  for pvm3.h to compile correctly
#include <sys/times.h> /* for times system call */
#include <sys/time.h>  /* for gettimeofday system call */
#include <pthread.h>

/*#define DEBUG 1*/

#define RANDOM_SEED   12345678 

//The main work routine
//void generateRandomNumbers(long long);  
void *generateRandomNumbers(void *);
double getMilliSeconds();

/* The main work routine */
//void generateRandomNumbers(long long int count)  
void *generateRandomNumbers(void *arg)
{
    struct random_data buf;
    int32_t result;
    char rand_statebuf;
    printf("hold 1\n");
    // This is the function that gives me a SegFault
    initstate_r(RANDOM_SEED, &rand_statebuf, 128, &buf);
    printf("hold 2\n"); 

    long long int* count = (long long int*) arg;
    //printf("Count for thread ID# %ld is %lld\n", pthread_self(), *count);
    long long int i;
    //long int x;

    srandom_r(RANDOM_SEED, &buf);
    for (i = 0; i < *count; i++) {
        random_r(&buf, &result);
#ifdef DEBUG
        printf("%ld\n", result);
#endif
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    long long int count, newCount;
    int numThreads;
    //pthread_t *tids;

    double timeStart = 0;
    double timeElapsed = 0;

    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <n>\n" ,argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    sscanf(argv[1],"%lld",&count); /* lld for long long int */
    sscanf(argv[2],"%d",&numThreads);
    pthread_t tids[numThreads];
    newCount = count/numThreads;

    timeStart = getMilliSeconds();  //And we are off

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<numThreads; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&tids[i], NULL, generateRandomNumbers, (void *) &newCount);
    //pthread_join(tids[i], NULL);
    }

    int j;
    for (j=0; j<numThreads; j++)
    {
        pthread_join(tids[j], NULL);
    }

    //generateRandomNumbers(count);
    printf("generated %lld random numbers\n", count);

    timeElapsed = getMilliSeconds() - timeStart;
    printf("Elapsed time:  %lf seconds\n",(double)(timeElapsed/1000.0));
    fflush(stdout);

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Maybe generateRandomNumbers is not thread-safe because of the static seed that gets updated with each call?

Comment: @Matthew, I am not familiar with pvm3, but does any of their in code documentation (comments) say anything about which functions are and are not thread safe?

Comment: @Matthew - another thought, again, not familiar with the library you are using, but many times with random generators, an init function, (perhaps such as initstate_r) is intended to be use once, say at the beginning of a process, to prime the pump.  Then subsequent calls would continue to generate pseudo random numbers until the process is stopped.  What does the documentation say about initstate_r?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, initstate_r's second param is supposed to be a char*,

You do:

```
char rand_statebuf;
printf("hold 1\n");
// This is the function that gives me a SegFault
initstate_r(RANDOM_SEED, &rand_statebuf, 128, &buf);
```

You pass it a pointer to 1 character which meets the requirement for a character pointer, however you need much more space than just one character. It should be:

```
char rand_statebuf[128];
initstate_r(RANDOM_SEED,rand_statebuf,sizeof(rand_statebuf),&buf);
```

Comment: Recommend  `initstate_r(RANDOM_SEED, rand_statebuf, sizeof(rand_statebuf), &buf);`  Also, is `128` known to also be sufficient?  Best I can tell is that it must be >= 8.

Comment: Some literature says "Values for the amount of state information   are 8, 32, 64, 128, and 256 bytes.  Amounts are rounded down to the nearest known value."  So would 256 be the most robust?